# Request/Response Transformers in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I want to transform each REST request/response. For eg.,

**REST Response :**

```
{
   "id" : "123,
   "name" : "dheepan"
}
```

**Typescript class**

```
class Person {
    id : number;
    displayName : string;
    _new : boolean;
    _edit : boolean;
}
```

So to convert the rest response to the corresponding Person class, i have written converter like,

```
interface PersonConverter {
   fromRestObject(person: any): Person;
   fromRestArray(persons : any[]) : Person[];
   toRestObject(person : Person) : any;
   toRestArray(persons : Person[]) : any[]; 
}
```

and before/after each rest call i can use the converter with the map operator,

```
.map(persons => new PersonConverter().fromRestArray(persons));
```

Now the issue is, as the application grows, the number of converters also grows and this approach looks ugly. And when there's an exception, it's bit extra work to identify whether the exception is from REST resource or Converter.  Is there any better approach to transform each request/response objects with Angular 5?

Comment: What do your converters do exactly, apart from mapping fields? If they don't do much, you have the same property names in your model and the json response, you don't need a converter

Comment: @David, 
1.We make parallel development of REST services and UI.  REST Attributes are changing often since its under development.. so we need converters to reduce the effort of refactoring as and when REST API changes.
2. to load relationship data. for eg, the Person class has an attribute AddressId and we need to fetch it eagerly, then this converter will make a REST call to `/address` service and populate that data to the Person class
3. It is not possible to have same model structure for Angular form and a POST rest service because of various reasons. 

Hope it answers your question!

Comment: Yes I understand now, but I can't think of any nicer solution. You could try using an interceptor if you want to do it in only one place though.